# Handling mulitple buttons and multiple on click events

Tags: android

I have about 9 buttons in my activity
As of now I initialize each one
with

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    });
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    });
```

and so on and on. 
How can I initialize them within an array and assign unique onclick element to each button?

. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this `button1.setOnClickListener(getClickListener('one'));`

```
public View.onClickListener getClickListener(final String as){
   return new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   };
}
```

And also add all the button to an array and then set the on click listener in a loop

** Edit: **

```
    Button[] btn = new Button[10];
    HashMap<String,Button> buttons = new HashMap<String, Button>();

    buttons.put("one", (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    buttons.put("two", (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    //put all your buttons like this

    for(String btnKey: buttons.keySet()){
        buttons.get(btnKey).setOnClickListener(getClickListener(btnKey));
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? I don't know how to initialize them as an array.

Answer (score 1):

i would go with a switch!

set all their onclick attributes to:

```
android:onclick="onClick"
```

and implement it in your activity like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button1:
           // your code;
           break;
           case R.id.button2:
           // your code;
           break;
       ...
           default:
           //your code
   }
```